# Can't set up time machine with 500G drive and 1TB samsung T7

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine

I erased the external drive (1TB samsung T7) and formatted with APFS (journaled). It backs up the first 220G of 480G or so. Then, it stops abruptly, complaining it has only 99M available. I'm not sure how this is possible, since my backup drive has 1T of space. What could be the problem?

(My OS version is 11.5.2. I want to get a proper backup before updating.)

Update: when I excluded Dropbox, it worked. The fact that I only have 40G of space on my hard drive probably adds to the problems.

Comment: Are you using Dropbox or OneDrive, with folders configured for Access on Demand/Selective Sync?  Time Machine will force the download of all the content marked as selective sync and try to write it to the backup.

Comment: @MarcWilson I do use Dropbox and I have smart sync enabled for a lot of folders. However, dropbox has not tried to sync any of these files when I tried to do a time machine backup.

Comment: I'll bite... how would you know?  Exclude the Dropbox folder from the TM backup and find out.

Comment: @MarcWilson Well I checked the sync history from the Dropbox app. But I'm trying a sync with dropbox excluded nevertheless.

Comment: And how much space on your internal 500GB drive?  It would be helpful to post a screenshot of the error message/"complaint".

Comment: @Redarm 40G or so. I excluded dropbox and it worked, so I'm unable to get a screenshot of the error as of now.

Comment: There you go.  Finder and TM don't know any better... here's TM trying to access this phantom file, so of course Dropbox feeds it the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TM is not complaining about only 99MB left on the backup disk, but about the `Macintosh HD` not having free space. It needs quite a bit to work with for snapshots etc.

In addition, as the other commenters have suggested, if you have Dropbox syncing stuff back, then that just adds to the problem. Also, check your `Bin` for anything else you can get rid of to free up space.

I had exactly the same issue the other day (except no Dropbox) on my 1TB MBP using TM to a barely half way full 2TB Samsung T7. Turns out I had a load of stuff in the `Bin` I'd forgot about, which left very little free space on `Macintosh HD`.

Comment: Thanks for that -- I'll do a proper cleanup.